# AZURE FHIR: How _lastUpdated transformed to ResourceSurrogateId

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, hl7-fhir

Continuing my research over AZURE FHIR (Sql Version), I found that the lastUpdated search parameter somehow is corelated to the ResourceSurrogateId field (in the Resource table).

Moreover, I believe both are the same but in different formats. However, I did not find any source explaining how the lastupdated (a date-time value) is transformed into the ResourceSurrogateId (numeric Value).

**Can somebody explain me how can I get a ResourceSurrogateId based on its original date-time value?**

> Test:
>   I run the followig FHIR REST API: `https://XXXXXXXXXXX/DeviceComponent?_lastUpdated=gt2019-07-01` and the actual query on the database was:

````
FROM dbo.Resource r
WHERE ResourceTypeId = @p1
    AND ResourceSurrogateId >= @p2
    AND IsHistory = 0
    AND IsDeleted = 0
ORDER BY r.ResourceSurrogateId ASC
OPTION(RECOMPILE)',N'@p0 int,@p1 smallint,@p2 bigint',@p0=11,@p1=32,@p2=5095809792000000000```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource surrogate ID encodes the datetime of insert to millisecond precision along with a "uniquifier" that comes from a cycling sequence on the database. The code that converts from a surrogate ID to datetime and back is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.SqlServer/Features/Storage/ResourceSurrogateIdHelper.cs).

You will not be able to get the surrogate ID from the datetime, but you will be able to get lower and upper bounds on it.